# Iteration of backbone fetch response

Tags: json, backbone.js, iteration

I am calling a rest webservice using `backboneCollection.fetch`
after fetching the results I am getting response as:

```
[{"projects":[{"id":1537512,"name":test},{"id":1537513,"name":test1}]}] 
//response =JSON.stringify(projects);
```

How can I iterate this one?

Comment: Do you mean, iterate through the collection after fetching ?

Comment: yea..iterate through the collection after fetching.. 
If i alert response.projects.lenghth i am getting response.projects is undefined

Comment: Feel free to mark a response as accepted. Help keep the site clean by not leaving questions open.

Answer (score 1):

you should override your collection's `parse` method:

```
... rest of collection...

,parse: function(response) {
    return response[0].projects;
}
```

this way, your collection will be comprised of the returned array of projects without the extra wrapper object.

check out the excellent documentation at http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you are getting undefined for response.projects is that if your response object is

```
[{"projects":[{"id":1537512,"name":test},{"id":1537513,"name":test1}]}]
```

as you stated, then your whole response is wrapped in an array.

If you were to take `response[0]` you would have

```
{"projects":[{"id":1537512,"name":test},{"id":1537513,"name":test1}]}
```

You should be able to take response.projects of this.

From there follow @Andbdrew's statement concerning Backbone's parse function.